# Can I create and configure a GCP project + Firebase completely from the CLI or a script?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcloud, firebase-cli

I am using gcloud + firebase cli to explore a reproducible way to create and configure a GCP + Firebase project.

I have created the GCP project using gcloud cli tool. I have then used firebase cli to run the command *firebase init firestore*.

Ulimately it ended up outputting...

> Error: It looks like you haven't used Cloud Firestore in this project before. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/my-project/firestore to create your Cloud Firestore database.

Is there a way I can "create my firestore database" using a cli tool or scripting api, instead of having to navigate to a web GUI tool and manually execute steps?

Comment: Your question is too broad. The simple answer is no, some tasks must be completed in the GUI. That list is evolving with more and more features being implemented as APIs. Edit your question to be more specific on one task that you need to do instead of specifying **GCP Project + Firebase completely from the CLI or script**. Google and Google Cloud comprise hundreds of services. Knowing every detail of every service would limit who can answer this broad of a question.

Comment: You will have the same issue in AWS and Azure. I am not aware of a cloud vendor that provides APIs for every feature. None of the clouds are **developer platforms**. They are production platforms for deploying applications and services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless Firebase do more behind the scenes, creating a Firestore instance could be as simple as this command from the [GCloud CLI reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/databases/create):

```
gcloud firestore databases create --region=us-central --project=my-project
```

The documentation for the entire create-provision cycle (from GCP's perspective) is [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/automate-database-create) - including [Terraform details](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/automate-database-create#create_a_database_with_terraform) (some commands may have been released since the docs were written).

Comment: This is not the answer. This command requires creating an app engine instances for some reason. I have no requirement for an app engine instance.

Comment: @Scorb I just opened up one of my Firebase projects in the Google Cloud Console and even though I don't actively use App Engine, an app engine project has been created for me (but nothing is deployed to it). Per the [docs I linked](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/automate-database-create): "Firestore depends on App Engine. You must activate App Engine to use Firestore." This would be Firebase doing more behind the scenes that I eluded to in my answer.

Comment: @Scorb - App Engine is used behind the scenes for many services and features.